# How to transparently track line numbers from a character stream in C#?

Tags: c#

I'd like to seek to an arbitrary point in a character stream and then get the corresponding line number.  In Java, this can be handled transparently with the java.io.LineNumberReader.getLineNumber() method.

What's the best way to go about this in C#?

Comment: I'm pretty sure its physically impossible to get the line number without reading through the file rather than seeking - I'd be interested to see how the Java implementation works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't anything like that in .NET Use the [ReadLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) method and track the line numbers yourself.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to derive your own stream class and override the read/seek/write functions such that you can track the new lines yourself.  Another possible solution is a method that operates on the stream to do what you want:

```
        static int LineNumber(System.IO.Stream s)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[s.Length];
            s.Read(buffer, 0, (int)s.Length);
            string text = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);            
            int idx = 0;
            int line = 0;
            do
            {
                idx = text.IndexOf('\n', idx);
                if (idx > -1)
                {
                    line++;
                    if (s.Position <= idx)
                        return line;
                    if (idx < text.Length - 1)
                        idx++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (line > 0)
                        return line;
                    else
                        break;
                }
            } while (true);
            return 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably Java has designed a stateful text stream reader and .NET would implement it within next 10 years.

If you are not going to wait you should write a wrapper class (stateful) around .NET `TextReader` Class which adds desired functionality to the class. You simply need to count new line characters as the stream is going forward. It's obvious this class would be slower than the original class so making this feature optional is a good idea.

Comment: Nah, what do we have lazy eval for? It is computed, when it has to be computed.